# How to store Deja Dup full backup remotely

Tags: duplicity, dejadup

I'm keeping a copy of all my Deja Dup backup in my Dropbox. To conserve disk space, I'm wondering if I can delete the local copy of the `duplicity-full.*.difftar`, keeping only `.sigtar` to allow future incremental backup. I did try move away `duplicity-full.*.difftar`, Deja Dup end up prompting for back up password, so assuming it's going to do another full backup instead of incremental.

Answer (score 0):

are you aware that duplicity, which deja dup is based on, sports a dropbox backend?

make sure you have the latest duplicity 
and 
see manpage sections Requirements, URL Format, a Note on Dropbox Access 
http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html

there are probably some howto's out there you can search&find.

..ede/duply.net

Comment: Yes, I do see that, though I'm not sure if the images is uploaded directly to Dropbox, which doesn't work with the slow internet connection I have. A full 6GB backup took 2 days to sync. Incremental backup is easier, but still could take at least an hour.